# How to send arrays from Python to C#

Tags: python, c#

I wanna send some arrays from python to C# so I can put the values in the array in a graph. How could I do this just by running the python file? I know that I have to write some code in C# as well to generate the graph and put the values in graph. but how could I link those two?

this is my code in Python. I'm getting some student numbers and the date they passed the exam. `row[0]` is the student number and `row[11]` is the day they passed. I wanna send the value `fastStudent` and `allPassedStudents` to C# so I can use these there to show in a graph

```python
csv_dict_reader = csv.reader(read_obj, delimiter=';',)
next(csv_dict_reader)
for row in csv_dict_reader:
    if row[11]:
        allPassedStudents.append(row[0])
        passedDate = datetime.strptime(row[11], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M') 

    if passedDate:
        if passedDate < end_date:
            fastStudent.append(row[0])
    print(fastStudent)
```

Comment: Do you have to plot in c#? Python has some easy-to-use plotting libraries - my preferred one is [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi sadly enough I have to use C#

Comment: It would help to know the order in which you want to execute your python and c# code: Do you plan on executing the python code for all rows in the csv first, and then execute the c# code, or do you want the c# code to plot values as each row is read by python? If it's the former, you could simply write a new csv file from the python script which contains all the values in `fastStudent` and `allPassedStudents`, and then read the file in the c# code. If it's the latter, it's going to be more complicated than that

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes I need to fetch the rows first in Python and then send the data to C# to plot the values. without using any csv files

Comment: IPC is quite an advanced and very broad topic. It is very hard to provide a concrete answer to the question as it stands now. Please work with your teacher to clarify what actually needs to be done and [edit] the question with details. (Side note - https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: Would a asp.net mvc web api based controller be good? i.e. python can send data in form post of json to an endpoint in c# ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Iron python](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3). It lets you call python code from c#. After installing it, you can run something like this in C#:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.ExecuteFile(@"yourfile.py", scope);
dynamic graphfunctionpy = scope.GetVariable("graph_function");
var result = graphfunctionpy(fastStudent,allPassedStudents);
```

This would call the graphing function defined in your python file with the two variables that you want to use.